# Conditionally perform build artifact archiviation

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to automate a jenkins build of mixed .NET solution.
The project is composed of a Web application, a WPF one and some other satellite assembiles.

Currently I'm builing the whole solution as

```
   stage("Build the solution")
   {
        bat("\"${msbHome}\" \"${slnName}\" /p:Configuration=\"${t}\" /p:PublishProfile=\"${t}\" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Profile=\"${t}\" /p:username=\"***" /p:password=\"***\" /nologo /t:Clean,Build" )

   }
  stage('Compress the WPF application')
  {
      def filename= t +"_" + buildRevision + "_client.zip";

         if (fileExists(filename))
        bat("del "+ filename);
      zip(zipFile:filename, dir:"output\\client\\" + t)

      archiveArtifacts artifacts: filename
   }

 stage('Compress the Web application')
{
     def filename= t + "_" + buildRevision + "_server.zip";

         if (fileExists(filename))
        bat("del "+ filename);
      zip(zipFile:filename, dir:"output\\server\\" + t) // <----This won't exist for Web deploy packages

      archiveArtifacts artifacts: filename
}
```

I've got different build profiles, some build and publish either the WPF and Web project, other ones performs a web deploy of the Web project and the publish of the WPF part.

Is there a way I can check if there's the output folder of the server part and if so compress it? otherwise I've to switch based on the pubish profile, but I dislike it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell and add the conditional zip statements in code